# WPF bug when using DataGrid and IDataErrorInfo?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, idataerrorinfo

I think I have stumbled upon a bug in WPF when textboxes in a DataGrid contains invalid data and are disabled.

When the textboxes contain invalid data and are disabled I can make the data (and binding?) magically disappear by clicking twice on the textbox with invalid data, click on another element in the row, then click twice on the textbox with invalid data. 
I made a small example which reproduces the problem. If you click twice on 121, one time on 55, then twice on 121 the 121 should disappear (and the binding will stop working?). Can anyone confirm it is a bug or am I doing something stupid?

WPF code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tests}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test header">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test header 2">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=Text2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests {get;set;}

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
            Tests.Add(new Test());
        }
    }

    public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Text2 { get; set; }
        public Test()
        {
            Text = "121";
            Text2 = "55";
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get { return "WTF!!!"; }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
}
```